# R Shiny get value from renderUI and HTML?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

If I have a text area generated in my shiny app via renderUI from HTML, how would I access the text here from shiny?

Minimum reproducible example (how would I get the value typed in "mytextbox" into my input?):

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("mytextbox")
)
server <- function(input, output){
  output$mytextbox <- renderUI({
    HTML('<html><textarea id="test" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea></html>')
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The reason I'm asking this instead of using Shiny's text area input is because there are other js and html parts involved with this particular use case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since you gave the element the `id` of "test", you can check the `input$test` value

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("mytextbox"),
  textOutput("value")
)
server <- function(input, output){
  output$mytextbox <- renderUI({
    HTML('<textarea id="test" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>')
  })
  output$value <- renderText(input$test)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I have to physically type something in that html text box for the input$test to be recognized, is there a reason why the input$test shows blank when the html text box is filled via another javascript function?

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what you are doing. Something needs to trigger a change event so the shiny js code can respond to it. Maybe it would be better to post as new question with more clarily.

Answer (score 1):

You can render another UI and put the contents of 'test' inside. like @MrFlick pointed out, to access the content of the textarea element you need input$test.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
    htmlOutput("mytextbox"),
    uiOutput('inputs') 
    )
)
server <- function(input, output){
    
    output$mytextbox <- renderUI({
        HTML('<textarea id="test" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>')
    })
    #render another UI
    output$inputs <- renderUI({ 
        tagList(textInput('text_test', '', input$test),
                radioButtons('radio_bttn', 'First choice is the texarea content',
                             choices = c(input$test, 'another option')))
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I have to physically type something in that html text box for the input$test to be recognized, is there a reason why the input$test shows blank when the html text box is filled via another javascript function?